# Bahamut IRCD on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ircd

I'm trying to run the Bahamut IRCD on my Amazon Linux AMI EC2 instance.  I've opened the appropriate ports in my security group, but any attempt to telnet those ports (6667-6669) gets a "connection refused" message.  Obviously, my IRC client also won't connect to the server.

In my ircd.conf file, I've got these three port blocks:

```
port {
    port    6667;         # Port to listen on
    bind    (my.ip.ad.dr);    # IP address to listen on
    flags   S;            # allow SSL connections on this port
};
port {
    port    6668;         # Port to listen on
    bind    (my.ip.ad.dr);    # IP address to listen on
};
port {
    port    6669;         # Port to listen on
    bind    (my.ip.ad.dr);    # IP address to listen on
};
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feeling dumb.  Just figured this out.  Needed to remove the bind lines if I want to be able to connect (I was using my server's IP, not my personal one) from any client.  Thanks!